# How do I run react native project via Xcode on new Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

The following undefined symbol errors appear when attempting to run my react native project via Xcode on my new MacBook. Do you know what may be causing this?

[image]

Please see PodFile:

[image]

This is the new error I'm now seeing:

[image]

And I am seeing one of my Product files in the Pods folder highlighted red:

[image]

Comment: The problem might be with the libraries inside the pod file, can you please post your pod file here ?

Comment: I've added the pod file

Comment: Can someone please help here? I've tried other the answer from this link which failed to resolve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71933392/react-native-ios-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64 . I made sure the environment was setup correctly.

Comment: Can you please try removing flipper related code in pod file ?

Comment: Thanks. I removed the flipper related code and received the errors above in the screenshot when re-running.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling Xcode and performing the react native environment set up again. I am able to launch new react native projects but I’m still unable to run my existing project. Can someone help please?

Comment: Can someone please help me here? I tried adding debug & release config to the pod file but that didn’t resolve the issue. I really don’t want to start a new project on my new laptop. Please

Answer (score 0):

First you have to setup react-native environment, and go to project library run npm install or yarn install and go to ios directory of project and run pod install, now you can open your workspace file in xcode.

follow this link
[setup react-native environmemnt](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)
to setup react-native environment

Comment: Can you please help? I’m able to launch new react native projects but not existing projects that I transferred from my previous MacBook. I used the link to setup the react native environment

Comment: okay, can you explain the problems which you are facing?

Comment: When running the project I am now seeing the error: "5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64". And I also see a file highlighted red under Pods > Product folder as shown above. PodFile was also updated to above shown

Answer (score 0):

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'projectName' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'projectNameTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Try this, replace projectName with your targetName